# Solving the Cauchy problem for $x'=f(x)$ with the condition $x(0)=g(x_0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Let $E$ be a Banach space and $f,g:E\to E$ diffeomorphism of class $C^1$.  $f$ is linear and  $f\circ g=g\circ f$ which imply:
>   $Dg(f(x))=f(g(x))\:,\:\forall x\in E$
>
> **i)** Prove the if x(t) is the maximal solution of $x'=f(x)$ with $x(0)=x_0 $then $g(x(t))$ is the maximal solution of the initial problem $x'=f(x)$ with $x(0)=g(x_0)$.
>
> **ii)** Deduce that $\phi_t$ is the flux of $x'=f(x)$ then $\phi_t\circ g=g\circ\phi_t$ for all $t$ in the respective maximal interval.

i) For the first part I assumed $g(x(t))$ to be the solution then I tried to verify if it was the solution for the initial problem.
$(g(x(t)))'=g'(x(t))x'(t)=g'(x(t))f(x(t))=g'(f(x(t)))=f(g(x(t)))$ which is the vector field for $\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=f(x)\\
x(0)=g(x_0)
\end{cases}$

However I am struggling to prove that $x(0)=g(x_0)$.

ii)

By part i) I am wondering if I could consider $\phi_t=g(x(t))$ so that $\phi_t\circ g=g\circ g=g\circ\phi_t$.

**Question:**

Are my answers right? How should I finish i)? If my answers are not right. How should I solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your assumptions are strange. $f$ is a vector field, mapping a base space into the tangent space. $g$ is an action on the base space. I would expect something like $f(g(x))=g'(x)f(x)$ as action on the vector field to obtain some kind of invariance. This is then also what you use in your proof. So can you check the correctness of your reproduction of the task?

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann             I copied the exercise correctly. $D$ stands for the derivative operator. You are right about $f$. I should not have called it a vector field. What I used in my proof was the following $g'(x(t))f(x(t))=g'(f(x(t)))=Dg(f(x(t)))=f(g(x))$, first step by the chain rule. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann        $f$ is linear and $f∘g=g∘f$ imply $Dg(f(x))=f(g(x))$ by the fact a linear operator derivative is itself  (f'=f).

Comment: Ok, that is true if you identify $f$ and $f'$ with the matrix/operator. If $f(x)=Ax$, then $f'(x)=A$ so that $Dg(Ax)=g'(Ax)A$ and $DAg(x)=Ag'(x)$ and equality of the left sides leads to equality of the right sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question to i), the formulation of the task is unfortunate. What they mean is that $\tilde x=g(x(t))$ solves $\tilde x'=f(\tilde x)$ with $\tilde x(0)=g(x(0))=g(x_0)$. Which means that the second time $x$ is used, here $\tilde x$, it is meant as general, abstract $x$ as subject of the ODE, with no relation to the earlier specified solution $x$.

Your approach to ii) has notational misunderstandings. The flux or flow of the ODE is a function $\phi(t;x_0)$ which as function of $t$ solves the IVP with $\phi(0;x_0)=x_0$. An alternative notation is $\phi_t(x_0)$ as family of isomorphisms so that one more easily formulate the group action $\phi_{s+t}=\phi_s\circ\phi_t$. What you have to show is $g(\phi(t;x_0))=\phi(t;g(x_0))$. This is essentially what was proven in i), only in a more complicated notation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am still stuck at point ii). I belive $\phi_t$ is associated to $x'=f(x)$ with $x(0)=x_0$. However I do not know how to treat the flux $\phi_t$, since I do not have a clear expression of what it is. How should I make the required deduction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $t\mapsto \phi_t(x_0)$ is the solution with $x(0)=x_0$. In the first part you showed that $t\mapsto g(\phi_t(x_0))$ is also a solution, now with initial condition $g(x_0)$. By uniqueness thus $g(\phi_t(x_0))=\phi_t(g(x_0))$.